# How to install ROS indigo in Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS Desktop 64-bit?

Tags: ros, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having problems with installation of Indigo in UBUNTU 14.04.3 LTS Desktop 64 Bit. I followed the installation instructions provided on ROS website. But following problems are occuring.

1. At step 1.3 when i run following in terminal:

   sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-key 0xB01FA116

following msg is displayed:

```
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.AyKV0NvoaE --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-key 0xB01FA116
gpg: requesting key B01FA116 from hkp server pool.sks-keyservers.net
?: pool.sks-keyservers.net: Host not found
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect: Connection timed out
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

---

Edit:

Since i m a beginner in Linux environment. I do not know much about the system and its requirements. It is also possible may be I have not configured the repositories properly. Bcoz following command is also not working properly.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

When i run it following message is displayed.

```
Err http://packages.ros.org trusty InRelease                             
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                             
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                             
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease              
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
Err http://archive.canonical.com trusty InRelease
Err http://packages.ros.org trusty Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'packages.ros.org'
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'extras.ubuntu.com'
Err http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'archive.canonical.com'
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg 
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'

Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch
http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch
http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch
http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch
http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg
Could not resolve 'packages.ros.org'

W: Failed to fetch
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg
Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch
http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg
Could not resolve 'extras.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/Release.gpg
Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/Release.gpg
Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/Release.gpg
Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch
http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg
Could not resolve 'archive.canonical.com'

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223996/how-to-install-ros-indigo-in-ubuntu-14.04.3-lts-desktop-64-bit?/) by [sajid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25560/sajid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-01-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-01-13**:
Could you try the following: `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key 0xB01FA116` and report back here?

**Comment by [sajid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25560/sajid/) on 2016-01-14**:
I tried this. It also gives same message.

**Comment by [Nouman Tahir](https://answers.ros.org/users/20072/nouman-tahir/) on 2016-01-14**:
seems you are behind some proxy server, else try changing to main fetch server in software sources.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-01-14**:
First: you cannot `apt-get update` until you've set up your keys properly. Second:

> Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'

seems to point to a problem with your network configuration. Are you behind a proxy? Can you browse the internet normally? Can you `ping archive.ubuntu.com` successfully?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-01-14**:
Also: please don't post an answer, unless you can actually *answer* your own question. If you have additional information or updates, please *edit* your original question (use the *edit* link/button for that). For console copy/pastes, please format using the *Preformatted text* button (`101010`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This keyserver is down (look at [this keyserver status page](https://sks-keyservers.net/status/)). Type instead:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
```

this was already asked [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/223702/ros-keyserver-down/).

---

Originally posted by [mmore](https://answers.ros.org/users/22937/mmore/) with karma: 51 on 2016-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sajid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25560/sajid/) on 2016-01-14**:
Its not working.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-01-14**:
@mmore: from the output @sajid posted, I'd say that there is an issue with his DNS setup. The server(s) might still be down, but the fact that even the `wget ..` is not succeeding points to other problems.